# Hide div if selection is empty

Tags: javascript

I have this code, if a selection is made on some text and it's not only a space, a div appears. But, if I do nothing on the div and the selection is removed. The div is still there. **Is there some to check if the selection is empty, then hide the div?**

```js
$("#actual_verse").mouseup(function() {
  var text = "";
  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }

  if (/\S/.test(text)) {
    // Tool Tip
    var ele = document.getElementById('tooltip');
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var rel1 = document.createRange();
    rel1.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal1'));
    var rel2 = document.createRange();
    rel2.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal2'));

    if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
      var r = sel.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
      var rb1 = rel1.getBoundingClientRect();
      var rb2 = rel2.getBoundingClientRect();
      //this will place ele below the selection
      ele.style.top = (r.bottom - rb2.top) * 100 / (rb1.top - rb2.top) + 'px';
      //this will align the right edges together
      ele.style.left = (r.left - rb2.left) * 100 / (rb1.left - rb2.left) + 'px';
      //code to set content
      ele.style.display = 'block';
    }
    // End of Tool Tip
  }
});
```

```css
/* Tool Kit */

#tooltip {
    position:absolute;
  display: none;
    border:grey solid 1px;
    background: #373737;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
  -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Chrome/Safari/Opera */
  -khtml-user-select: none;    /* Konqueror */
  -moz-user-select: none;      /* Firefox */
  -ms-user-select: none;       /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
  user-select: none;           /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                  not supported by any browser */

}

#cal1{
    position:absolute;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    overflow:none;
    z-index:-100;
}
#cal2{
    position:absolute;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:none;
    z-index:-100;
}

.boxes {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

#blue_box {
  background: #AAF6FF;
}

#green_box {
  background: #D6FFAA;
}

#orange_box  {
  background: #FFBF98;
}

#purple_box {
  background: #D7D5FC;
}

#red_box {
  background: #FF9B9F;
}

#yellow_box {
  background: #FFF8AA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='actual_verse' class='context'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, doctus expetendis no vel. At vis doming viderer prompta. Ut vis consul atomorum pericula, an sed sonet suscipit lobortis. Eos tale atqui iriure ne, eos in delenit corpora, nec laudem everti ei.</span>
<div id='cal1'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='cal2'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='tooltip'>
  <div id='blue_box' class='boxes' title='blue_mark'></div>
  <div id='green_box' class='boxes' title='green_mark'></div>
  <div id='yellow_box' class='boxes' title='yellow_mark'></div>
  <div id='orange_box' class='boxes' title='orange_mark'></div>
  <div id='purple_box' class='boxes' title='purple_mark'></div>
  <div id='red_box' class='boxes' title='red_mark'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
document.getElementById("divId").style.display=(/\S/.test(text))?"block":"none";
```

Comment: It's not working. But it's not your fault, I didn't provide enough code. I'll edit my answer...

Comment: Not sure what you need  -  ele.style.display=(/\S/.test(text))?"block":"none";